# Wireshark does not see local traffic when running as normal user

Tags: security, localhost, wireshark

I am running some HTTP requests between a local Firefox and both local and remote web servers.

I capture traffic with Wireshark using the interface `any`.

- When running Wireshark as my normal user, I don't see the traffic between the local Firefox and local web server (I see other packets, though).
- When running Wireshark as root *(don't try this at home)*, I see all traffic.

What is causing this problem?
How to see all traffic, including local, while running Wireshark as my normal user?

*Notes:*

- I am using `any` in both cases.
- My normal user is a member of the `wireshark` group.